# Testing with console output for multiple devices (iPhone/iPad) at the same time with Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging, device

Is it possible to debug / run Xcode iPhone/iPad application project with multiple testing devices at the same time and see console outputs for all of them?
I am developing bluetooth application and I would like to test it in full activity mode, being able to see NSLog, etc.. in console for at least 2 connected devices.

I can see that Xcode 4 provides possibility to run multiple debug sessions at a time, but console outputs only logs for one of them.
Is there a way to set up Xcode  (some build/run settings in the scheme) to be able to see logs for multiple testing devices connected and debugged at the same time?

Comment: I’m not sure you can debug multiple devices at the same time. If you want to see console logging of multiple devices/hosts or applications, consider using [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger).

Comment: To see console logging for other device than already debugged it is enought to turn on Organizer and for connected device logs. See my comment to the pheelicks answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a nice way of doing it. One hack that I've found is that if you have two instances of Xcode running, you can have two Organizer windows open, each viewing a different log

Launch the 2nd instance using Terminal:

`open <path to Xcode.app>/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`

Comment: Thank You for a hint. For being able to see NSLog messages which is the most important in my case it was even simpler: Debug application on the first device in standard way and just turn on Organizer -> Devices -> [Another Device] -> Console. NSLog messages will be visible as Warning: ...

Comment: Superb answer. At least for 2 devices (USB limit in MacBook :-( ). Tested with Xcode 4.0.1. Debugging 2 devices at the same time runs smoothly. Thank You for pointing out how to run multiple instances of Xcode.

Answer (score 26):

I know this is an old question, and the above method of using the console works, but I just discovered a method I like better (I don't really like working with two windows all the time, especially with full screen Lion).

Run the debugger on both devices, then you can switch between the two just above the logging console.

[image: switch between device logs]

Select your device and it will show the corresponding logs below

Comment: You can also navigate your running processes from the Debug Navigator (cmd+5). Just select the process in the left pane and the console output will change accordingly.

Comment: This solution is fine whilst both sessions are running, but once you close them down, there's no way to see both console logs that I know of.

Comment: Switching between sessions is not very convenient, especially if you need to compare something

Answer (score 3):

Another option is: Connect your two devices. In XCode navigate to Window -> Organizer. You'll see a list of all connected devices. And here you can click on your second device and select `Console`. Good thing is, you see the two Console windows at the same time!