# How do you launch an iOS app from the command line while debugging?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, ios-simulator

I'd like the ability to launch an iOS app from the command line with a parameter. Ideally, I'd like to do this on an attached debugging device + in the simulator, but currently I have no idea how to do this at all, or if it is even possible.

Comment: What is your end goal? Command line debugging, or to just the ability to debug the simulator and a device at the same time? If it is the latter then I will expand my comment on the answer below into it's own answer.

Comment: FWIW, I have app that runs on the phone and also can be run on the Mac command line as a Mac app.  Obviously there are some parts unique to each environment, but the "meat" of the app is shared between the two.  This allows me to feed large test libraries through the command line app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to run and debug iOS app on device and simulator at the same time.

This link might be useful for you.

[Testing with console output for multiple devices (iPhone/iPad) at the same time with Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557633/testing-with-console-output-for-multiple-devices-iphone-ipad-at-the-same-time)

Comment: That is not true, in Xcode you can debug multiple iOS device and one simulator at the same time. You can select your device from the list hit play, select another device and hit play. Once more than one device is debugging the stop button has a down arrow. If you press the stop button you will get a list of running devices that you can stop individually.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. I do not have 2 devices to check it right now. I searched about it and found that you are right. Thanks